# Getting permission denied on k8s initContainer while running sh file

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I have a k8s YAML file with 2 containers. `initContainer` and the main container. I am using a volume to mount a script file to be run in `initContainer` but I am getting `permission denied` error. 
Here is the snippet.

```
  volumes:
  - name: casacm-script
    configMap:
      name: {{ include "oxauth.name" . }}-casacm-script
```

and in `initContainer` I mount it like

```
 initContainers:
  - name: {{ include "oxauth.name" .}}-init 
    image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl:latest
    command: 
      - sh
      - -c 
      - /scripts/casacm.sh   
    volumeMounts:
      - name: casacm-script
        mountPath: "/scripts/casacm.sh"
        subPath: casacm.sh
```

Comment: Usually a Docker image is a better place to keep and distribute actual code, like a shell script.  You could then manage permissions with `RUN chmod ...` in the Dockerfile if it was necessary.

Comment: In this case, my task was to create a chart. The Dockerfile had been handled by someone else. But I get what you saying. Thanks for the response @DavidMaze

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your volumes to below to add permission.

```
volumes:
  - name: casacm-script
    configMap:
      name: {{ include "oxauth.name" . }}-casacm-script 
      defaultMode: 0777
```